# Django : Retrieve objects from relation

Tags: django, python-2.7, orm, foreign-keys

I am new in Django (1.11 used) and I read this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/topics/db/models/) but I didn't find a clear answer for my question : How to retrieve the objets

With an example , Suppose I have the following models :

```
class StudentCollaborator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code_postal = models.IntegerField()
    collaborative_tool = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_skills(self):
        return SkillHistory.objects.filter(student=self.user, value="acquired").values_list('skill')
```

The skill history :

```
class SkillHistory(models.Model):
    """
        The reason why a Skill is acquired or not,
        or not yet, when and by who/how

    """

    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
    """The Skill to validate"""
    student = models.ForeignKey('users.Student')
    """The Student concerned by this Skill"""
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    """The date the Skill status was created"""
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=(
        ('unknown', 'Inconnu'),
        ('acquired', 'Acquise'),
        ('not acquired', 'None Acquise'),
    ))
    """The Skill status : unknown, acquired or not acquired"""

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    reason_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    """Why the Skill is validated or not"""

    by_who = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['datetime']
```

and finally the skill class :

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    """[FR] Compétence

        A Skill can be evaluated through questions answered by a student.
        Thus, when evaluated, a Skill can be acquired by a student, or not.

    """

    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, db_index=True)
    """The Skill reference code"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    """The Skill name"""

    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How can I do to retrieve Skill objects (instead of their ID) in the get_skills function; thanks ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use something like `return SkillHistory.objects.filter(student=self.user, value="acquired").values('skill__code', 'skill__name', 'skill')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the Skill object directly . But you can get skill attributes by this query .

```
SkillHistory.objects.filter(student=self.user, value="acquired").values('skill__name', 'skill__code')
```

Comment: I don't know : your answer matches the lost example in the docs in django I found ...

Comment: @jy95 the above answer is exactly how a Django ORM query is done. This is in accordance of the above example also.

Answer (score 1):

```
Skill.objects.filter(skillhistory_set__student=self.user, skillhistory_set__value="acquired")
```

Filter using related name.

Comment: I think values won't retrieve the objects see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values.

Comment: Cannot test now sorry :(

Comment: @jy95 You got the chance to check whether it works ?

Comment: No, it just not compilying XD